A highly space-efficient embedding of prime factorization problem using the Ising model
What's the idea?
I'm trying to embed the prime factorization problem into the form of a PUBO. To do so, let $p$ and $q$ be two real positive numbers. We can represent these two numbers as binary numbers, which itself can be represented as vectors, $\pmb{p}$ and $\pmb{q}$, where $\pmb{p}$ and $\pmb{q}$ both have $k$ elements. I define a new vector $\pmb{x}$ by concatenating $\pmb{p}$ and $\pmb{q}$ as follows:
$$p_i \in \{ 0,1\}$$
$$q_i \in \{ 0,1\}$$
$$ \pmb{x} = (p_1, \ldots, p_k, q_1, \ldots, q_{k})^T$$
Now I define the following matrix $Q$:
$$Q = \sigma_x \otimes \alpha$$
where $\alpha$ is a $k \times k$ matrix that its elements are defined like this:
$$\alpha_{ij} = 2^{2k - (i+j)}$$
and
$$
\sigma_x = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This formulation, allows us to make $Q$ in a way that the product of numbers $p$ and $q$ is equal to the expression $\frac{1}{2}\pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x}$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x} = pq$$
Now, I can also do this for $(pq)^2$:
$$\frac{1}{4}\pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x}\pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x} = (pq)^2$$
Now coming back to our original problem, we want to find the $p$ and $q$ so that:
$$pq = N$$
To do so, we can convert it into this optimization problem:
$$\min_{p,q} f(p,q) = \min_{p,q} (N-pq)^2$$
and using the PUBO form, we can convert $f$ to:
$$f(p,q) = N^2+ (pq)^2 - 2 N pq$$
$$f(p,q) = N^2+ \frac{1}{4}\pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x}\pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x} - N \pmb{x}^T Q \pmb{x}$$
Of course, this approach assumes that $\pmb{p}$ and $\pmb{q}$ have the same length of bits. To generalize this, we can simply move the separation point of vector $\pmb{x}$ from middle, one step at the time to get different lengths. This converts the complexity of the problem into:
$$O(N \log(N))$$
To solve this PUBO, I've tried simulated annealing and it works:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tqdm import tqdm


def beta(N):
    pauli_x = np.array([[0, 1], [1, 0]])

    def matrix_values(i, j):
        return 2**(2*N - (i+1)- (j+1))
    matrix = np.fromfunction(matrix_values, (N, N))

    # tensor product of pauli_x and matrix
    matrix = np.kron(pauli_x, matrix)
    
    return matrix

def preprocess(p, q):
    binary_p = bin(p)[2:]
    binary_q = bin(q)[2:]

    # do a padding to make the length of binary_p and binary_q equal
    if len(binary_p) < len(binary_q):
        binary_p = '0'*(len(binary_q) - len(binary_p)) + binary_p
    elif len(binary_q) < len(binary_p):
        binary_q = '0'*(len(binary_p) - len(binary_q)) + binary_q

    x = np.array(list(binary_p+binary_q), dtype=int)

    return x


def simulated_annealing(B, pq, n_iterations=1000, T_start=100, T_end=0.1):
    # Initialize
    x = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=len(B))
    x[-1] = 1  # q must be odd
    x[len(x)//2] = 1  # p must be odd

    T = T_start
    energies = []
    best_x = x.copy()
    best_H = float('inf')

    # Initial energy calculation
    xBx = x @ B @ x
    H = pq**2 + xBx**2 // 4 - pq * xBx

    # Create tqdm progress bar
    pbar = tqdm(range(n_iterations))
    
    for i in pbar:
        # Generate new state
        j = np.random.randint(0, len(x))
        x_new = x.copy()
        x_new[j] = 1 - x_new[j]  # Flip the bit
        
        # Calculate energy difference efficiently
        delta_xBx = 0
        for k in range(len(x)):
            delta_xBx += B[j, k] * (x_new[j] - x[j]) * (x[k] + x_new[k])
        

        xBx_new = xBx + delta_xBx
        H_new = pq**2 + xBx_new**2 // 4 - pq * xBx_new
        
        # Calculate energy difference efficiently using vector operations
        delta_x = x_new - x
        delta_xBx = 2 * (delta_x @ B @ x) + (delta_x @ B @ delta_x)
        
        xBx_new = xBx + delta_xBx
        H_new = pq**2 + xBx_new**2 // 4 - pq * xBx_new

        # Calculate energy difference
        delta_H = (H_new - H) / pq**2
        
        # Decide whether to accept the new state
        if delta_H < 0 or np.random.random() < np.exp(-delta_H / T):
            x = x_new
            H = H_new
            xBx = xBx_new
        
        # Cool down
        T = T_start * (T_end / T_start) ** (i / (n_iterations - 1))
        energies.append(H)

        # Update best state
        if H < best_H:
            best_x = x.copy()
            best_H = H
        if best_H == 0:
            break
        # Update tqdm description with current best_H
        pbar.set_description(f"Best H: {best_H:.4e}")

    energies = np.array(energies)

    return best_x, best_H, energies

p , q = 241, 251
pq = p*q
L = (np.floor(np.log2(float(pq))).astype(int)) //2 + 1

B = beta(L)

x, H, energies = simulated_annealing(B, pq, n_iterations=10_000, T_start=1e-1, T_end=1e-5)


# get back the values of p and q
p_o = int(''.join(map(str, x[:L])), 2)
q_o = int(''.join(map(str, x[L:])), 2)
print(H)
print(p_o, q_o)

plt.plot(energies, color='b', linestyle='-', label='Energy')
plt.yscale('symlog')
plt.xscale('symlog')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Energy')
plt.hlines(0,xmin=0, xmax=1.4*len(energies), color='black', linestyle='--', label='Optimal Solution')
plt.xlim(0, 1.4*len(energies))
plt.legend(loc = 'center left')
plt.show()


Note that my code assumes the same length of bits for both numbers, but as mentioned before, it can be generalized pretty easily. This code successfully factors the number 60491 to 241 and 251.
What's the catch?
The catch is that the simulated annealing is not a good way of optimization for large $N$. There are far better Ising machines for these types of tasks, but the problem is the fact that they are designed to work with QUBOs, not PUBOs. But now, I tell my suggestion:
We should be able to solve this using a modified version of the Simulated Bifurcation algorithm.
It is highly parallelizable, and it reaches to the solution in orders of magnitude less time. I also think there are tons of other optimizations in the embedding itself. Plus, I believe we should be able to combine this approach with classical algorithms such as Sieve of Eratosthenes. Please tell what you think about my approach. Any comment would be greatly appreciated.

What unique properties of the structure of the factorization problem are you relying on?

How do you come to $N \log N complexity? QUBO and PUBO are exponentially complex problems.

@MartinVesely That's the "space complexity" of number of qubits, not the time complexity.

@MarkSpinelli At the moment, no special property. But I'm proposing that it is probable to use them in this type of embedding.

@AmirhosseinRezaei: I see, thanks.


Please tell what you think about my approach.

There have been several papers doing basically what you are doing. Create a multiplication circuit whose ground state is the factoring solution. Apply QAOA or annealing or some over generic optimization technique. See that it works at small scales, because everything works at small scales. Then just hope it'll work at large scales, even though there's no proof given to expect it to keep working.
There have been some instances in classical computing of things working surprisingly well. For example, the simplex algorithm has worst case exponential time but basically solves linear optimization problems in practice in polynomial time. But this is rare. It's more common for things to fall apart as you scale them up. I personally expect all these "maybe we can factor with optimization" approaches to go nowhere.
Read
https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=6957
and
https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=4447
and maybe
https://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/qml.pdf

This really doesn't answer my question. Please see this paper. Where using a classical computer, we can solve a QUBO that is NP. All I'm saying is that using my embedding and a modified version of Ising minimizers, we should be able to solve PUBOs such as factoring problem much more efficiently.
